# Automatically chaining multiple tests on broken JVMs

Tags: java, linux, maven, jvm

I am running a series of performance tests from a linux command line using maven + testng on Java8.

Most of these tests run until they break the JVM (typically by running out of memory) at which point I manually set up and run another test from a new JVM.

I would like to be able to automatically chain multiple tests to run back to back, but I don't know of a way to accomplish this when the previous test leaves the JVM in an unusable state.

Is there a way for me to reset a broken JVM (or something along those lines) via Java / Maven / Linux / some other program / framework?

I have access to either Oracle's JDK or to OpenJDK, but if need be I may be able to convince the server admin to install another JDK.

Comment: Are your tests executed with JUnit / Maven Surefire plugin? Then I assume you can use an @After (or @AfterClass, depending on the case), on which you can call `System.gc()`, forcing a garbage collection. That should probably assist with the OOM and bring you back to a _working_ condition.

Comment: @JChrist [`System.gc()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--) is just a suggestion to the JVM. It's not guaranteed that anything is done at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `maven-surefire-plugin` allows tests to be run in a forked JVM. The information is [on the plugin page](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html), but you'll need something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

That will create a new JVM for each test run. You can tweak this by changing the `forkCount` (for example, to ensure tests don't run in parallel or do) and use the `reuseForks` to determine whether the JVMs should be recycled.